# Journey Builder Throttling over a week (Automatic calculation)

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, send-throttling

We have data that comes in once a week (On a Monday) and needs to be throttled in a journey over a week, (Monday - Sunday). The Data is not static and will change week on week, this week could be 100K, next week 150K, then 80K, following week 200K...

Is there a way that JB can automatically calculate the split per day (over the week) and throttle?

The only way I can think to do this is to split it with wait periods but I'm not too sure how I would split based on percentages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of a Random Split and wait activities:

- use the random split to split the audience into equal batches by percentage, 100% over 7 days would give you roughly 14% daily
- use wait activities on each branch to delay the execution of the campaign, first branch 0 days wait, second branch 1 day wait, etc

Read more here: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sf.mc_jb_split_journey_contacts_at_random.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the solution provided by Zuzanna is the way to go in your case. But I'll drop some other options just in case:

1- Use **send throttling**. Send Throttle emails during the hours you specify every day, starting when you send the email until all emails are sent. **Not very suited to your use case, but it can be added as a security layer to avoid sending too many emails simultaneously.**

> You can use Send Throttling for these reasons:
>
> - To control inbound traffic to a website caused by the interest
>   generated from an email. High inbound traffic can result in server
>   crashes due to too many people visiting.
> - To limit the number of emails
>   sent to a particular domain each hour.

2- Use **Wait by attribute activity**. In this case, **you need to do the segmentation outside of Journey Builder using SQL for example**.

**Resources**:

- https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=mc_es_send_throttle.htm&type=5
- https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_wait_for_a_date_based_on_an_attribute_value.htm&type=5&language=en_US